# Validate Geolocation latitude and longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, geocoding

I have a Ruby on Rails model `Camping` with `#latitude` and `#longitude` attributes.

This should be validated. It must be validated so that:

- The values are correctly formatted. E.g. 48.8582 and 2.2945 but also 48.8 and 2.2. Any precision should be allowed. I store them as Float, any addtitional validation needed or advised?
- They are within valid ranges (0-90). Or should I allow negative numbers, or numbers above and below 90?

I am not interested in whether on this point is an actual valid address (sea, northpole, whatever, as long as it is a valid point on earth).

I am using [geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) gem, but for now, input is simply a pair of lat/lon textfields. Geocoder is merely of interest for this question because it may have utility-methods (which I cannot find) to validate a lat/long pair.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm not aware of any methods in Geocoder to check that but you could just use rails validations

```
validates :latitude , numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to:  -90, less_than_or_equal_to:  90 }
validates :longitude, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: -180, less_than_or_equal_to: 180 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 and greater, the correct answer would be:

```
validates :lat, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: -90,  \
  less_than_or_equal_to: 90 }
validates :lng, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: -180,  \
  less_than_or_equal_to: 180 }
```

Comment: Note: Reason reversing the order of the validator doesn't work i.e. validates :lat, numericality: {less_than_or_equal_to: 90, greater_than_or_equal_to: -90}